# This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

My Android project crashes when I want to show data on UI display. I tried so many solutions from Stackoverflow. Still those solutions did not work for me. Error log and Activity class is given below.

Probable issue is occuring due to Looper. When loop is running then I am facing this issue.

```
Error log is below:
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been
>   closed, making it unusable.
>                                                                                at io.realm.internal.OsResults$Iterator.(OsResults.java:45)
>                                                                                at
>   io.realm.OrderedRealmCollectionImpl$RealmCollectionIterator.(OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java:558)
>                                                                                at
>   io.realm.OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.iterator(OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java:239)
>                                                                                at io.realm.RealmResults.iterator(RealmResults.java:62)
>                                                                                at
>   com.dayspringltd.dlog.activity.ReportingActivity$1$1$1$1.onClick(ReportingActivity.java:159)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4652)
>                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19311)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Main issue is occurring the ReportingActivity file line number 159:Code is below:

```
public class ReportingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Realm Operation
    private Realm realm;
    RealmResults<Visit> resultsInCount;
    RealmResults<Visit> resultsOutCount;
    RealmResults<Visitor> resultsVisitor;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.report_activity);

        //initialize Realm database instance
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        init();
        initClickListeners();
        try {
            realmTransaction();
        }finally {
            realm.close();
        }
    }

private void realmTransaction() {
        // Realm transaction
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {

                //All fields value of Visit table
                resultsInCount = realm.where(Visit.class).notEqualTo("visitInDateTime","0").findAll();
                resultsOutCount = realm.where(Visit.class).greaterThan("visitOutDateTime",0).findAll();
                //All the data from Visitor class
                resultsVisitor = realm.where(Visitor.class).findAll();
                Log.d("Visitor:",resultsVisitor+"");

                //Total IN count
                totalINCount = resultsInCount.size();
                Log.d("inCount:", totalINCount+"");
                //Total OUT count
                totalOUTCount = resultsOutCount.size();
                Log.d("outCount:", totalOUTCount+"");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        in_value.setText("" + totalINCount);
                        out_value.setText("" + totalOUTCount);


                        //All report operation will be performed here
                        generate_report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                // custom dialog
                                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ReportingActivity.this);
                                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.report_custom_dialog);
                                dialog.setTitle("Report");
                                //Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                                //window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.white);


                                Button all_report = dialog.findViewById(R.id.all_report);
                                all_report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        ReportingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        ReportingViewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        dialog.dismiss();


                                        TableLayout stk = findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutReport);
                                        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(ReportingActivity.this);

                                        TextView tv0 = new TextView(ReportingActivity.this);
                                        tv0.setText(" Name ");
                                        tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                        tbrow0.addView(tv0);

                                        TextView tv1 = new TextView(ReportingActivity.this);
                                        tv1.setText(" Phone ");
                                        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                        tbrow0.addView(tv1);

...................
.....................


                                        tbrow0.addView(tv3);

                                        stk.addView(tbrow0);

                                        `for(Visitor visitor : resultsVisitor)` {
                                            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(ReportingActivity.this);

                                            TextView t1v = new TextView(ReportingActivity.this);
                                            t1v.setText("");
                                            t1v.append("" + visitor.getVisitorName());
                                            t1v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                            tbrow.addView(t1v);

                                            ..............

                                            stk.addView(tbrow);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

Noe that I have another Activity Named ConfirmaitonActivity.java which takes care of inserting data to the Realm DB. When I want to show the data, data is coming from Realm DB correctly but when I wanted to show the data to the UI display following line creates issue

```
for(Visitor visitor : resultsVisitor) {
```

Initially I tried to close the Realm db inside onDestroy() method but this did not work too.

So, what can be done to resolve the Loop issue in Realm DB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable + RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447871/this-realm-instance-has-already-been-closed-making-it-unusable-rxjava)

Comment: No, it's because you're closing Realm in onCreate rather than onDestroy for whatever reason. But you also won't be able to access the RealmResults that you obtained from the background thread Realm instance that you get as a parameter in executeTransactionAsync.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Initially I closed the Realm in onDestroy. But the result was same.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you also tell what is the exact reason I won't be able to access the RealmResults; may be that will help me to find out the issue in more details?

Comment: Because it's on a different thread, AND it will be closed when the transaction on said background thread  is done. Which is why you're getting the exception you're getting

Answer (score 1):

At last I am able to solve the Looper thread issue, I implemented RealmChangeListener and worked like a charm :)  I referred the below link and I got the solution. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#best-practices

From Realm official documentation:

On the UI thread and all other Looper threads, all RealmObjects and RealmResults are automatically refreshed when changes are made to the Realm. This means that it isn’t necessary to fetch those objects again when reacting to a RealmChangedListener. The objects are already updated and ready to be redrawn on the screen.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults<Person> allPersons;
    private RealmChangeListener realmListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Realm realm) {
            // Just redraw the views. `allPersons` already contain the
            // latest data.
            invalidateView();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.addRealmChangeListener(listener);
        allPerson = realm.where(Person.class).findAll(); // Create the "live" query result
        setupViews(); // Initial setup of views
        invalidateView(); // Redraw views with data
    }

    // ...
}
```