# Realm crashes after realm.close()

Tags: android, realm

I have the following code:

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
return realm.use { realm ->
    realm.where(BookItem::class.java).findAll()
}
```

I obtain the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been
>   closed, making it unusable.

I supose that is because the where function didn't finished when close happens. How should I do this instead?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this answer help you find a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41449847/2480714

Comment: How about changing the codes -> ```if(!realm.isclose()) { realm.close() };``` This way is the way realm official documents recommend.

Comment: Realm crashes after realm.close() - you are trying to make queries after you closed the realm?

Answer (score 0):

read the documentation on how to properly close realm [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
try {
  // ... Do something ...
} finally {
  realm.close();
}
```

> I supose that is because the where function didn't finished when close happens. How should I do this instead? no since findAll() is not async. maybe you have a code that call the realm instance.

Comment: Check EDIT, I'm doing exactly what you proposed and still the same error.